# How to use variable as event name in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

This is probably a very simple fix. I just can't seem to figure this out.

I've stored event names in variables and would like to use them in the code as shown in the pseudo-code below but it does not seem to be working for me. See the comments in the code below.

```
var EVENT;
if (something == true) EVENT = "hover";
else EVENT = "click";

mynav = function() {
   $(".nav").not(".nav2").bind(EVENT, function() { // EVENT works fine here
   ......
   ......
   ......
   } (EVENT == "hover")?', function() {}':''; ); // If EVENT is "hover", I want to display function()... Not sure how to make it work here....
}
```

Comment: @Zenith I got it working. For detecting `(EVENT == "hover")`, I ended up doing it directly using PHP within jQuery, something like this - `<?php 
  if ($nav_event == "hover") { 
   echo (!$present)? ", function () { .........; }": ""; 
  }
 ?>`. It was a while back. I can't remember if the other solutions worked nicely in my situation. Probably MohamedAli and codeiz's solutions below works too.

Answer (score 0):

create the function then call it where ever you want

```
function MyHover(){
alert('MyHover()');
} 

function MyClick(){
alert('MyClick()');
} 

var EVENT;
if (something == true) EVENT = "hover";
else EVENT = "click";

mynav = function() {
   $(".nav").not(".nav2").bind(EVENT, function() { // EVENT works fine here
   ......
   ......
   ......
   } (EVENT == "hover")? MyHover() : MyClick() ; ); // If EVENT is "hover", I want to display function()... Not sure how to make it work here....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try make your function separated like this:

```
function myHover () {}

function myClick() {}
```

and in your code call your function:

```
mynav = function() {
   $(".nav").not(".nav2").bind(EVENT, function() { // EVENT works fine here
   ......
   ......
   ......
   } , ((EVENT == "hover")?:myHover : myClick ));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var EVENT = something == true ? "hover" : "click";
mynav = function() {
    $(".nav").not(".nav2").bind(EVENT, EVENT === "hover" ? function() {
        // Hover function
    } : function() {
        // Click function
    });
}
```